# Как подключиться к Atlas M0 (Free Tier) кластеру MongoDB?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, mongodb

Пытаюсь подключиться к Atlas cluster-у используя Java driver [MongoDB версию 3.6](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/driver-connection/#java-driver-example).

Пишу такой код:

```
  MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://admin1:mypassword@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
  MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

Получаю ошибку об исправлении `mongodb+srv`:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string is invalid. Connection strings must start with 'mongodb://'
    at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.<init>(ConnectionString.java:203)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:176)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClientURI.<init>(MongoClientURI.java:158)
    at project.Bot.check(Bot.java:30)
    at project.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:104)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:309)
```

Хотя версия драйвера указана в POM файле :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Тогда пишу так, используя MongoDB версию 3.6 (при этом убирая `+srv`приставку):

```
 MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://admin1:mypassword@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

В результате IDE сообщает об ошибке такого плана:
[image]

```
com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.mongodb.net}}]
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)
    at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:201)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:206)
    at com.mongodb.operation.CountOperation.execute(CountOperation.java:53)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:185)
    at com.mongodb.MongoCollectionImpl.count(MongoCollectionImpl.java:170)
    at project.Bot.check(Bot.java:36)
    at project.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:103)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1249)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
    at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:309)
```

Когда запускаю процесс `mongo` моя база данных  добавляется по адресу `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017`, хотя я хотел добавить БД в сам кластер. 
Прочитал в [документации](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/driver/tutorials/connect-to-mongodb/) о том, что нужно запускать команду `mongos`, но как правильно нужно прописать, не могу до конца понять.

У кластера есть, конечно, пользователь администратор с паролем. Подключиться к самому кластеру через клиент Compass и оболочку shell я могу, но сама база (которую в программе добавляю) - не добавляется. `mongod` запущен. Судя по описанию, похожая проблема возникала [здесь](http://discourse.metabase.com/t/connect-to-mongodb/3597).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне нужно исправить при написании кода. (При необходимости могу предоставить полный код программы.)

Comment: *java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0.mongodb.net* - у вас конечный адрес не резолвится в DNS, и клиент не знает, куда ему стучаться

Comment: @etki, то есть мне нужно разобраться с DNS в кластере, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: @etki, может проблема в том, что у меня не запущен `mongos` и не прописаны реплики в конфиг-файле, как думаете?

Comment: В данный момент у вас совершенно точно не доходит коннект до кластера. Проще всего заменить доменное имя на айпишник. В каком состоянии у вас кластер - вот этого я вам уже не скажу.

Comment: @etki, когда я прописываю вместо кластера локальный айпи, у меня вылетает похожая ошибка: `com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadTimeoutException: Timeout while receiving message}, caused by {java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out}}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Подробнее опишу действия и решение**

я пробовал подключиться к кластеру с помощью `driver3.6 or later`, в таком случае две разных ошибки выпадали:

1-я: когда я прописывал `mongodb+srv://user:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`, то получал  `Connection strings must start with 'mongodb://'`.

2-я: тогда я убирал `+srv` и прописывал аналогично, но таким образом:
`mongodb://user:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true`, в этом случае у меня вылетала ошибка `com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary}. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketException: cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net}, caused by {java.net.UnknownHostException: cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net}}]`.

**Решение:**
подключиться наконец-то я смог с помощью `driver3.4 or earlier`, прописав так:
`mongodb://user:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true`.

---

**Update:** если вы все же захотите использовать драйвера `3.6+` версий, то вместо подключения в формате (+ избежать аналогичных ошибок, указанных мною в вопросе)

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI("mongodb+srv://admin1:mypassword@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
```

пишите так:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://admin1:mypassword@cluster0-ox90k.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true");
```

**Обратите внимание**, что пароль должен быть не в скобках вида `<>`.

**Дополнительно:** если вдруг у вас после обновления драйвера появится ошибка вида `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/client/MongoClients`, попробуйте изменить конфигурации запуска в `Edit Configurations`.

Answer (score 1):

client_url:

```
mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0-00lyc.mongodb.net/databasename?retryWrites=true
```

как вариант:

```
mongodb://username:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-00lyc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-00lyc.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-00lyc.mongodb.net:27017/databasename?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin
```

Подставьте свои username, password, databasename. А вообще у них там есть кнопка получить строку подключения Connect->YouApp->Driver 3.6:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное! Да, я так и пробовал, я нажимал "connect", далее "Connect your application" и смотрел 3 вариант "View driver connection examples", где расписывались примеры в док-е. А первый вариант я не проверил c версией 3.4, когда прописал `mongodb://user:password@cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true"`, кластер подключился успешно.