# Как убрать исключение Prematurely reached end of stream, используя Java Driver 3.4+ в mongoDB? (во время вставки)

Tags: java, mongodb

Я вставляю документы в **capped collection**, пишу так:

```
           // получить документ с необходимыми полями
            Document found = collection.find().first();
            String getTitle = (String) found.get("title");
            String getUrl = (String) found.get("url");
            String getImg = (String) found.get("img");
            String getPrice = (String) found.get("price");

            // документ, который мне нужно получить в новом виде
            Document doc = collection.find(new Document("title", getTitle)
                    .append("url", getUrl)
                    .append("img", getImg)
                    .append("price", getPrice)
                    .append("sent", true)).first();

            // если документ не существует, я вставляю как новый
            if (doc == null) {
             collection.insertOne(new Document("title", getTitle)
                   .append("url", getUrl)
                   .append("img", getImg)
                   .append("price", getPrice)
                   .append("sent", true));
        }
```

Это называется - **перезапись документов**. Я вставляю новые документы с дополнительным полем вместо старых без одного поля. То есть в начале коллекции удаляется документ, а вместо него появляется новый в конце коллекции.

Документ, который я заменяю выглядит так:
[image]

Вместо него я вставляю новый в таком виде:
[image]

Процесс вставки новых вместо старых документов происходит нормально до момента пока не вылетает исключение:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:88)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:491)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:221)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveReply(CommandHelper.java:134)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.receiveCommandResult(CommandHelper.java:121)
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:32)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:43)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.UsageTrackingInternalConnection.open(UsageTrackingInternalConnection.java:46)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool$PooledConnection.open(DefaultConnectionPool.java:381)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:96)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultConnectionPool.get(DefaultConnectionPool.java:82)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServer.getConnection(DefaultServer.java:72)
    at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.getConnection(ClusterBinding.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnectionSource(OperationHelper.java:237)
    at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:212)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:482)
    at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:79)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759)
    at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl$FindOperationIterable.first(FindIterableImpl.java:207)
    at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:148)
    at project.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:347)
```

Предполагаю, что ошибка в строчке:

```
Document found = collection.find().first();
```

Пробовал решить проблему, используя такой [сниппет](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079876/mongosocketreadexception-prematurely-reached-end-of-stream-after-a-period-of-i/39524128#39524128) (у меня free Tier M0 cluster):

```
 List<ServerAddress> List = new ArrayList<>();
            List.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net", 27017));
            List.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net", 27017));
            List.add(new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net", 27017));

            char[] password = "mypassword".toCharArray();
            List<MongoCredential> cred = new ArrayList<>();
            cred.add(MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "db_feed", password));
            MongoClientOptions optionsBuilder = MongoClientOptions.builder()
                    .readPreference(ReadPreference.primaryPreferred())
                    .requiredReplicaSetName("Cluster0-shard-0")
                    .maxConnectionIdleTime(60000)
                    .build();

            MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(List, cred, optionsBuilder);
```

Но в таком случае, получаю другое исключение:

```
 com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting for a server that matches ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primaryPreferred}. Client view of cluster state is {type=REPLICA_SET, servers=[{address=cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}, {address=cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream}}]
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createTimeoutException(BaseCluster.java:369)
        at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.selectServer(BaseCluster.java:101)
        at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:75)
        at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding$ClusterBindingConnectionSource.<init>(ClusterBinding.java:71)
        at com.mongodb.binding.ClusterBinding.getReadConnectionSource(ClusterBinding.java:63)
        at com.mongodb.operation.OperationHelper.withConnection(OperationHelper.java:210)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:482)
        at com.mongodb.operation.FindOperation.execute(FindOperation.java:79)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo.execute(Mongo.java:772)
        at com.mongodb.Mongo$2.execute(Mongo.java:759)
        at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl$FindOperationIterable.first(FindIterableImpl.java:207)
        at com.mongodb.FindIterableImpl.first(FindIterableImpl.java:148)
        at project.Bot.onUpdateReceived(Bot.java:347)
```

Судя по тому, когда это исключение встречается, кажется, что это из-за форматирования строчки с подключением, потому что у меня уже такая ошибка была при подключении [драйвера версий 3.6 и больше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/844156/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%83-mongodb). (все упиралось в `+srv` приставку, которая не позволяла нормально работать с драйвером новых версий от 3.6 и больше). Обратил внимание, что в других яп, как Python, решают вопрос `+srv` подключением [отдельного модуля](https://github.com/getredash/redash/issues/2603). Не имею понятия, как в Java такое реализовывать, т.к. похоже на костыль.

Кстати, когда я подключаюсь с версии драйвера Java 3.4 `com.mongodb.MongoTimeoutException: Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting` уходит сама собой:

```
MongoClientURI connectionString = new MongoClientURI("mongodb://admin1:mypassword@cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true");
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

Буду рад услышать мнения по своей проблеме, заранее спасибо.

---

Аналогичный вопрос уже задавал на [английском стеке](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52577486/how-to-avoid-an-exception-prematurely-reached-end-of-stream-using-mongodb-java-d).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была решена с помощью соединения форматом (используя параметры `maxIdleTimeMS`, `ssl` и `authSource`):

> [maxIdleTimeMS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.maxIdleTimeMS) - максимальное количество миллисекунд, которое соединение может оставаться бездействующим в пуле перед удалением и закрытием.

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://user:mypassword@cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&maxIdleTimeMS=5000");
```

---

Как вариант можно вручную прописать учетные данные (используя java driver `3.6+` версий):

`admin` - это база данных, в которой пользователи определены в Атласе;

`user` - это имя юзера;

`mypassword` - это пароль;

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential("user", "admin", "mypassword".toCharArray());
        MongoClientSettings settings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .credential(credential)
                .retryWrites(true)
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings(builder ->
                        builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
                .applyToSslSettings(builder -> builder.enabled(true))
                .applyToClusterSettings(builder -> {
                    builder.hosts(Arrays.asList(
                            new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-00-ox90k.mongodb.net", 27017),
                            new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-01-ox90k.mongodb.net", 27017),
                            new ServerAddress("cluster0-shard-00-02-ox90k.mongodb.net", 27017)
                    ));
                    builder.requiredReplicaSetName("Cluster0-shard-0");
                })
                .build();

        MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create(settings);
```

1. > При определении имен хоста укажите все имена узлов набора реплик. Это
   >   разрешит java.net.UnknownHostException.
2. > Вы не можете использовать короткое имя DNS с соединением `mongodb+srv`.